# Вертикальное выравние в блоке картинок и текста по подвалу

Tags: html, css

Привет. 
Есть набор горизонтальных блоков.
Как в блоке вертикально выровнять картинки и текст-описание прибить снизу...
Сдесь проблема в том, что картинки разного размера.

```
<td class="image">
<img src="">
<div class="align-bottom">
text
</div>
</td>
<td class="image">
<img src="">
<div class="align-bottom">
text
</div>
</td>
<td class="image">
<img src="">
<div class="align-bottom">
text
</div>
</td>
```

`vertical-align :middle` и картинки по вертикали выровнены. 
Но как быть с блоком текста? 
`position:absolute` скажете вы. Но тогда текст будет наезжать на картинку. 
Оптимально, когда блок с тектом имеет динамический размер, но если можно сделать с фиксированным, то пусть будет...

А да, текст также на 1 уровне.

Answer (score 1):

Очень своеобразный код, конечно, если уж делаешь таблицами, то действительно лучше сделай так, как тебе посоветовал densmith, должны помочь эти ресурсы: http://htmlbook.ru/html/table ,    http://htmlbook.ru/html/td , попробуй поиграть с объединением ячеек и т.д., меньше проблем и выглядит посолидней.

Answer (score 0):

Если таблицей решил делать, то размещай в 2 ряда: 1 ряд — картинки, 2 — описания к ним. Так меньше вероятных косяков вылезет.

А по-нормальному два варианта:
 1. Картинки в квадратный див с    `overflow:hidden` запихивай.  
 2. Либо    делай `<img style="height: Xpx" src="" />`.

Comment: нельзя обрезать картинки . Они подружаются в оригинальном размере. Там шаблон smarty не позволить в  TR  следующий запихнуть текст.

Comment: <img style="height: Xpx" src="" />